# Bash source -- select the right function when two sourced files have the same function name?

Tags: bash, shell-script, function

My bash script sources a script file (call it `file2.sh`) according to an argument. (It is either sourced or not.) The script `file2.sh` contains a function "foo" (call it a modified or improved version of foo).

The script also sources another file (`file1.sh`) which contains the original function "foo". This one (`file1.sh`) is always sourced (and it has other functions that are required).

I need the function "foo" in `file2.sh` to override the "foo" in file1.sh (if `file2.sh` is sourced).

Furthermore, I need to do this in any scripts that my main script calls. Several of those called script files also source `file1.sh`. They are expecting the original "foo" function. But I need to make them call the improved "foo" without modifying them.

In other words, if my main script includes `file2.sh`, I want any script (which is called by my main script) that sources `file1.sh` to use "foo" from `file2.sh` instead. And I can't change any of the other files except my main script. (Or if I do change them, I need them to work correctly when `file2.sh` is not sourced by the main script.)

Comment: Why do your files have `.sh` extensions if they are `bash` scripts? Are they `sh` or `bash` scripts?

Comment: @Stephane Chazelas: These are bash scripts. What is the right file extension? And what is wrong with the ".sh" extension?

Comment: If they are not written in `sh` syntax, I'd find using a `.sh` extension misleading. If using `bash` specific syntax, a `.bash` extension would make more sense. `bash` and shells in general don't care anyway how the files are named, it's just a cosmetic issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can flag your function as 'read only' in file2.sh.

Note: this will cause warnings when file1.sh later tries to define (redefine) the function.

Those warnings will appear on stderr and could cause trouble.  I don't know if they can be disabled.

Further note: this MIGHT cause the scripts to fail, if they are checking the return status of the function definition.  I think that there is also a bash option that can be set that would cause a non-zero return status anywhere to abort execution of the script.  Good luck!

Can you modify file1.sh?  Simply using conditionals to check if the function is defined before defining it would be a more robust solution.

Here is an example of usage of 'readonly'.

```
hobbes@metalbaby:~/scratch$ mkdir bash-source-test
hobbes@metalbaby:~/scratch$ cd bash-source-test
hobbes@metalbaby:~/scratch/bash-source-test$ cat > file2.sh
#!/bin/bash
fname(){
  echo "file2"
}

readonly -f fname
hobbes@metalbaby:~/scratch/bash-source-test$ cat > file1.sh
#!/bin/bash
fname(){
  echo "file1"
}

readonly -f fname
hobbes@metalbaby:~/scratch/bash-source-test$ cat >top.sh
#!/bin/bash 
if [ $1 ]; then
source file2.sh
fi  
source file1.sh

fname
hobbes@metalbaby:~/scratch/bash-source-test$ chmod +x *.sh
hobbes@metalbaby:~/scratch/bash-source-test$ ./top.sh 
file1
hobbes@metalbaby:~/scratch/bash-source-test$ ./top.sh hello
file1.sh: line 4: fname: readonly function
file2
hobbes@metalbaby:~/scratch/bash-source-test$
```

Comment: both of your suggestions are very helpful. I will experiment with both of them.

Comment: can you give an example of using conditionals to check if the function is defined before defining it? I'd like to try that approach. (I'll also google around and see if I find an example.)

Comment: @MountainX, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85880/determine-if-a-function-exists-in-bash for various techniques for determining  if a given name exists as a function.

Comment: A recent edit removed the bash warning message regarding the attempt to alter a readonly function.  I rolled back the edit because the purpose of my answer is to demonstrate the mechanics of read-only functions.

Answer (score 1):

If those scripts are indeed interpreted by `bash` (and not in `sh` emulation mode), and if `file1.sh` defines but doesn't *use* `foo`, you could redefine the `source` and `.` commands in such a way that upon sourcing `file1.sh`, it makes sure `file1.sh` doesn't redefine `foo`, for instance by aliasing it away to something else:

```
$ cat file1.sh
foo() { echo original foo; }
$ cat file2.sh
foo() { echo new foo; }
$ cat main.sh
file2_sourced=false
source() {
  case ${1##*/} in
    (file2.sh)
      file2_sourced=true;;
    (file1.sh)
      if "$file2_sourced"; then
        alias foo=original_foo

        builtin source "$@"; local "ret=$?"
        unalias foo
        return "$ret"
      fi;;
  esac
  builtin source "$@"
}
.() { source "$@"; }

source file2.sh
source file1.sh

foo
original_foo

$ bash main.sh
new foo
original foo
```

Or possibly more appropriate:

```
source() {
  shopt -s expand_aliases
  if [ "${1##*/}" = file1.sh ] && command -v foo > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    # foo already defined, make file1.sh define original_foo this time
    alias foo=original_foo
    builtin source "$@"; local "ret=$?"
    unalias foo
    return "$ret"
  else
    builtin source "$@"
  fi
}
```

That is: only prevent `file1.sh` from **re**-defining `foo`.

Now, if those other scripts that `main.sh` calls are *executed* as opposed to being *sourced*, you'd need to export those `source` and `.` functions in `main.sh`:

```
export -f source .
```

Actually, it's also possible to do it *without* modifying `main.sh`, by calling it as:

```
env BASHOPTS=expand_aliases source='() {
  if [ "${1##*/}" = file1.sh ] && command -v foo > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    # foo already defined, make file1.sh define original_foo this time
    alias foo=original_foo
    builtin source "$@"; local "ret=$?"
    unalias foo
    return "$ret"
  else
    builtin source "$@"
  fi
}' .='() { source "$@"; }' bash main.sh
```

Comment: Isn't simply sourcing the files in order as in my answer enough? I have the sneaky suspicion that it isn't since both you and @daveloyall chose much more complex routes.

Comment: @terdon, my understanding was that the OP had no control on the order the `file1.sh` and `file2.sh` were sourced and they could be sourced multiple time from scripts he could not modify (why we don't know).

Answer (score 1):

I have never written anything but small bash scripts for basic sysadmin and automation tasks so I have very little experience with sourcing functions from other files. This may therefore be very naive or not portable or something but, at least on my system and in most programming languages I know, if you redefine something it stays redefined.

In other words, as long as you make sure you source `file1.sh` *before* `file2.sh` and export the function afterwards, you should always be exporting the function from  `file2.sh` if it has been loaded and from `file1.sh` if it has not:

```
$ cat file1.sh 
#!/bin/bash
fname(){
  echo "BBBBB"
}

$ cat file2.sh 
#!/bin/bash
fname(){
  echo "CCCCC"
}

$ cat foobar.sh 
#!/bin/bash
source file1.sh
if [ $1 ]; then 
    source file2.sh;
fi
export -f fname;
./run_function.sh

$ cat run_function.sh 
#!/bin/bash
fname
```

Any scripts called (eg `./run_function.sh`) will have whichever `fname` was defined *last*, so they will load the one from `file2.sh` if it has been sourced and from `file.sh` if it has not:

```
$ ./foobar.sh
BBBBB
$ ./foobar.sh hello
CCCCC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think probably the easiest answer here is to get the function out of those script files.

```
#file[12]
#foo() { : removed; }
. ./foo.fn
#and rest of script

#foo.fn
foo() { : old version is always defined; }
[ -z "${NEWFOO:+1}" ] ||
foo() { : new version defined only if $NEWFOO; }

#your caller script
export NEWFOO=1
case $srcarg in (./file1) unset NEWFOO;; esac
#or however ^that part^ is usually done
. "$srcarg"
#and rest of script
```