# When writing a bash script, how does the script know which usage() to call?

Tags: bash, function

Let's say I write a bash function like so:

function.sh

```
usage () {echo "No arguments are needed";}

myfunction () {

if [[ $# -qt 0 ]] ;
then
   usage
fi

echo "Hello World"
}
```

Then I `source function.sh`. However, I have another script with `usage()` defined there too and I have sourced it too.

I run `myfunction -myWorld` and I hit the `usage()` call and it calls the correct one somehow.

How does bash know which `usage()` to call?

Comment: whichever one is the most recently defined in the current shell context is the one that gets executed.

Comment: @Jeff I'm afraid no. Do you mean that the other script is also sourced? If so, before or after `function.sh`?

Comment: @cas If that's the case, how would I scope the usage to the usage() calls from the function.sh script?

Comment: @AdminBee Let's say one before and another after

Comment: i have no idea what your question means. care to rephrase it?

Comment: if you mean "how do I ensure the **right** usage function gets called in any script?" then 1. don't redefine the function, don't source another script that you know is going to redefine the function, or 2. use different names for the functions in different scripts.   a function name can only have one definition at a time. redefine it, and the old definition is replaced by the new.....same as what happens when you assign a new value to a variable. or 3. if you must source a script that defines `usage()`, then define the local version **after** sourcing that script.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash source -- select the right function when two sourced files have the same function name?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85376/bash-source-select-the-right-function-when-two-sourced-files-have-the-same-fu)

Comment: just in case you're tempted to try, you can define a function within another function, but there's still no nested functions, e.g. this would redefine the global function `bar` every time `foo` runs: `foo() { bar() { echo bb; }; echo ff; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question, as it currently stands, is that Bash calls the *last defined version* of the function.

Using two modified versions of your example:

`function1.sh`

```
usage () { echo "Usage from function1.sh - No arguments are needed"; }

myfunction1 () {
  if [[ $# -gt 0 ]] ;
  then
    usage
  fi

  echo "Hello World"
}
```

`function2.sh`

```
usage () { echo "Usage from function2.sh - No arguments are needed"; }

myfunction2 () {
  if [[ $# -gt 0 ]] ;
  then
    usage
  fi

  echo "Hello World"
}
```

Then running

```
$ source function1.sh
$ source function2.sh
$ usage
```

will give the output

```
Usage from function2.sh - No arguments are needed
```

---

Note that in your script:

- `-qt` should be `-gt`, and;
- some spaces were missing in the `usage()` - around the `echo`

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to deprive the poster above me as the correct answer, since he outright answered my question.

However, I do want to post a followup.

Instead of the function being sourced, I added the directory the function.sh lived in to PATH and renamed the file to myfunction. On the very last line of the file myfunction is `myfunction $@`.